# Hypergeometric Distribution over an interval

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

In a village with 2000 people, 100 people suffer from Alzheimer's disease. On a certain day, 40 people are admitted to a hospital.

**Calculate the probability that between $15$ and $25$ people (inclusive) of the patients admitted have Alzheimer's disease.**

My attempt:

Let $X$ be the patients admitted who have Alzheimer's disease. 
$$P(15 \leq x \leq 25) = P(X=25) - P(X=15) = \frac{\binom{100}{25} \binom{1900}{15}}{\binom{2000}{40}}-\frac{\binom{100}{15} \binom{1900}{25}}{\binom{2000}{40}} $$

**What is the expected number of patients who have Alzheimer's disease?**

$$ E(X) = 40 \frac{100}{2000} =2$$

Is this right?

Comment: Presumably you are supposed to assume that the events of Alzheimer's disease and being admitted to hospital are independent.  That's not exactly a realistic assumption.

Comment: No.  $(X = 25)$ is the probability that exactly $25$ people have Alzheimers (and likewise for $15$).  Their difference is not equation to the probability that a number between them is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability is wrong. Note that
$$P(15\leq X \leq 25) = P(X \leq 25) - P(X \leq 15) = \sum_{k=15}^{25} P(X=k).$$

The expected number is correct.

Comment: is there a way to derive the exact probability for the first question?

Comment: You just calculate all the probabilities $P(X=15)$, ..., $P(X=25)$ and add them up.

Comment: did I set set up the problem right? It appears I mixed them up. Should N=2000 n=100 m=40 or N=2000 m=40 n=100?

Comment: can one use a binomial distribution for this problem? Where n=40 and p=0.05?

Comment: You can't use a binomial distribution. You can use this distribution if the population would be infinite and if the change of encountering someone with Alzheimer is 0.05. Here we use the hypergeometric distribution because the population is _finite_.